# Adding query parameter to Paging 3: Java

Tags: java, android, mvvm, paging, android-paging-library

I am implementing Jetpack Paging 3 library for my recyclerview, which gets data from API.
My API also has one more filtering parameter on top of page parameter.I want to set value for that paramenter from Fragment when some buttons have clicked. As I am using Java, I cannot find sample codes for my case.

This is my ViewModel:

```
public class FragmentMyPostsViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
public LiveData<PagingData<Post>> pagingDataLiveData;
MyPostsPagingSource moviePagingSource;
Pager<Integer, Post> pager;
MutableLiveData<Integer> query;

public FragmentMyPostsViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    query = new MutableLiveData<>();
    init();
}


private void init() {

    moviePagingSource = new MyPostsPagingSource(getApplication().getApplicationContext(), query.getValue());
    pager = new Pager<>(
            new PagingConfig(20),
            () -> moviePagingSource);
    CoroutineScope coroutineScope = ViewModelKt.getViewModelScope(this);
    pagingDataLiveData = PagingLiveData.cachedIn(PagingLiveData.getLiveData(pager), coroutineScope);

}

public void setStatus(int status) {
    query.setValue(status);
}

public LiveData<Integer> getStatus() {
    return query;
}
```

}

I tried to set value from fragment. But as `init()` method called when Viewmodel has instantiated, I could not set value to query.

Fragment:

`mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(FragmentMyPostsViewModel.class); mViewModel.setStatus(2); mViewModel.pagingDataLiveData.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), postPagingData -> myPostsRecyclerViewAdapter.submitData(getLifecycle(), postPagingData));`

How can I set filter query value from Fragment in Java?
Any tips, help will be appreciated

Comment: How were you able to use `PagingDataAdapter` in Java? I could never resolve it. I think Google purposefully made it difficult to use in Java because they want to kill it